# spring + SQLite in multi-threaded application

Tags: java, spring, sqlite

I'm developing an application that uses SQLite database and spring. I have problems when multiple threads try to modify the database - I get an error:

'The database file is locked'

I have a single datasource configured:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:sample.db" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
</bean>
```

and in each thread I have a separate instance of the JdbcDaoSupport that performs an insert to the database:

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(
  "insert into counts values(15)"
);
```

The function that performs the database update is transactional (I've tried all isolation levels, in each case I get the same error).

The same code works fine, when using other database (MySql).

How can I solve this (without adding a 'manual' synchronization in my code)?

Comment: How concurrent do you expect your app to be?  Recall that, by design, SQLite is intended to be a replacement for fopen() and -not- for MySQL.  If you need an RDBMS that has been designed to handle 2PL or MVCC for concurrent data access, then you may wish to consider another RDBMS.  MySQL, HSQLDB, or Derby all have real client-server support.

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried it, but I'd suggest that, given that SQLite supports only one connection at a time, you should configure your data source to only ever create one connection.

I think that would be something like the following...

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:sample.db" /> <
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="1" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just catch and retry.  This is normal SQLite behaviour.

[edit:] SQLite will retry itself; this error is thrown if the retries don't work within a certain period.  You can increase the period in various ways: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I have the perfect answer for you -- [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB) and the [SQL API](http://bit.ly/g06gVO). Last year Berkeley DB combined it's storage engine with the SQL layer of SQLite, providing a combined product that offers the best of both worlds. The ubiquity and ease of use of SQLite, with the concurrency, performance, scalability and reliability of Berkeley DB.

Why will this address your problem? Because Berkeley DB is completely SQLite compatible, but implements a different, more concurrent lock manager. This means that in Berkeley DB you can have multiple update threads accessing the database at the same time. There are a couple of interesting white papers on the subject, written by Mike Owens (the author of "The Definitive Guide to SQLite"): [Technical & Performance Evaluation](http://bit.ly/hKdxTK) and [Benefits and Differences](http://bit.ly/eyIwjC).

Disclaimer: I'm the Product Manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm slightly biased. However, you will find that the Berkeley DB SQL API addresses **exactly** the issue that you bring up -- how to allow concurrent read/write operations in SQLite.

Comment: What is the licensing for Berkley DB like? Can I distribute it with a commercial application without cost?

Comment: You can find the Berkeley DB license here: http://bit.ly/g7h1mf. Basically it's a dual license. Open source use for open source projects. Commercial license for closed source applications or to get Oracle Support.

Comment: As another alternative, HSQLDB (http://www.hsqldb.org) is free, is available under a GPL-like license, is now in version 2.3.0 and has been continuously developed for over 10 years.  It has real client-server (or stand-alone) support, a mature JDBC 4.1 driver, has nearly complete support for ANSI SQL:2008, and supports multiple access through both 2PL and MVCC models.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring, you can leverage the [`SingleConnectionDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html). For my uses (300+ inserts / second), this works just fine.

```
@Bean
public DataSource jdbcDataSource() {
    SingleConnectionDataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:stats.db");
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Quote from SingleConnectionDataSource documentation "Obviously, this is not multi-threading capable."

Comment: @PhoneixS The actual queries are not, no, but Spring handles the synchronization as long as you use spring jdbc classes like JdbcTemplate.