# Is it possible to create standalone JavaFx application that uses Spring Jdbc and Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, javafx

As i am new to JavaFx and of course spring jdbc, i am in blocker state. My application is almost ready and i have even created installation file for windows using inno setup. This installation file works fine on my system but when i run on another system it does not run; probably due to missing database and its server. So, i need a standalone application that manages all the database and other requirements itself through installer. After research i found many people suggesting to use Sqlite or hsqldb. Do i really have to use these database, can't i create standalone application that uses existing technology i.e. spring jdbc and mysql.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. Unfortunately you will have to install MySQL to the client machine where you want your application installed.

Comment: so do i have to switch to sqllite or hsqldb if i want to run on client machine without using mysql server.

Comment: Depends on your requirement. If you don't want to install RDBMS servers, by all means.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are going to have a separate `mysql` database server . you can very well `Spring-Jdbc` for the standalone programs.

```
<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="" />
    <property name="url" value="" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

can be configured in the `DispatceherServlet.xml` to connect with the database

Comment: No, i am not going to have database server. I need something like in android means all in one.

Comment: i am just using spring jdbc for persistance so i dont have dispatcherservet.xml. I have managed these information in a class.

Comment: Yes you can configure it with the sql lite also. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117248/spring-sqlite-in-multi-threaded-application

Comment: so i cannot use mysql without using its server in my standalone app!!

Comment: Yes. but you can also configure the database (SQL lite) without `dispatcher.xml` like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315672/how-to-configure-spring-mvc-with-pure-java-based-configuration

Comment: But you have an option if the user of the standalone has the mysql server running in its own machine with the configurations you have

Comment: so final answer is No you cant create standalone application that uses mysql without using mysql server yah?

Comment: NO not like that.you have to install MySQL to the client machine where you want your application installed.